# Reset password doesn't update my password in mongodb base

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am first time making APIs about forgot password and then reset password.
I am facing strange issue. There is not a single error, it gives me success status that password is updated. The problem is that in my database password is NOT updated.

User schema:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, min: 6, max: 255 },
  password: { type: String, required: true, min: 4, max: 1024 },
  resetLink: { data: String, default: "" },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Users", UserSchema);
```

Forgot password: (when user click forgot password and writes an email, this happens:

```
router.post("/forgot-password", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email } = req.body.email;

    //check if user is alredy in database
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (!user) return res.status(400).send("User doesn't exist");

    // create token
    const token = jwt.sign({ email: user.email, _id: user._id }, secretKey, {
      expiresIn: "15m",
    });

    // generate resetUrl link using the token and id
    const link = `http://localhost:3000/api/users/reset-password/${user._id}/${token}`;

    res.send("password reset link has been sent to an email");

    // SEND EMAIL
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: "*******",
      port: 587,
      secure: false,
      auth: {
        user: "*******",
        pass: "*******",
      },
    });
    let info = transporter.sendMail({
      from: '"Reset password" <*********>', // sender address
      to: req.body.email, // list of receivers
      subject: "Hello", // Subject line
      html: `<p>Visit the: ${link}</p>`,
    });

    user.updateOne({ resetLink: token });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json(err);
  }
});
```

Change password process
Firstly get method

```
router.get("/reset-password/:id/:token", async (req: any, res: any) => {
  const { id, token } = req.params;

  // Check if ID is valid
  const user = await User.findOne({ _id: id });
  if (!user)
    return res.status(400).send("User doesn't exist");

  try {
    const verify = jwt.verify(token, secretKey);
    res.render("reset-password", { email: user.email });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json(err);
  }
});
```

And then post method

```
router.post("/reset-password/:id/:token", async (req: any, res: any) => {
  const { id, token } = req.params;
  const { password } = req.body.password;
  const { password2 } = req.body.password2;

  // Validate if user is alredy in database
  const user = await User.findOne({ _id: id });
  if (!user) return res.status(400).send("User doesn't exist");

  try {
    const verify = jwt.verify(token, secretKey);
    // validate if password 1 and password 2 MATCH -> NOT YET

    // Update password
    const password = req.body.password2;
    bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, (err: any, salt: any) => {
      if (err) return res.json(err);
      bcrypt.hash(password, salt, async (err: any, hash: any) => {
        await user.save({ password: hash });
        res.send("Password is updated!");
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json(err);
  }
});
```

And I would alse be very happy, if someone could tell me or give me an advice, if there should me some changed regards to better security.

**Update:**
I will be using then Angular for frontend, so I am not even sure, if the get method in change password is needed (where i just make         res.render("reset-password", { email: user.email });
) An explanation of this line would be perfect

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: `user.save({ password: hash });` returns an promise, you could try to await it

Comment: I did, and it still doesn't update password in my database :/

Comment: You should sanitize the user input, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-sanitize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass `password2` to the `hash` function instead of generating a new variable and change the way you set the new password.
Plus, you should `await` the `save()` function:

```
router.post("/reset-password/:id/:token", async (req: any, res: any) => {
  const { id, token } = req.params;
  const { password, password2 } = req.body;

  // Validate if user is alredy in database
  const user = await User.findOne({ _id: id });
  if (!user) return res.status(400).send("User doesn't exist");

  try {
    const verify = jwt.verify(token, secretKey);
    // validate if password 1 and password 2 MATCH -> NOT YET

    // Update password
    bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, (err: any, salt: any) => {
      if (err) return res.json(err);
      bcrypt.hash(password2, salt, async (err: any, hash: any) => {
        user.password = hash
        await user.save()
        res.send("Password is updated!");
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, strangly after this I am getting error in my terminal: ValidationError: Users validation failed: password: Path `password` is required.

Comment: There was an error with `req.body` destructuring, see edited answer.

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem. Now it is getting updated. May I just ask you this: Why is firstly needed the get method in change password process and what does     res.render("reset-password", { email: user.email }); do? Do I even need this in MEAN stack application? because I am not sure if I will do any rendering like that way

Comment: I assume you do need the `res.render()`. It looks to me as the code responsible for sending the HTML template of the page for resetting the password. I think you could remove the `res.render()` if you implement the `reset-password` route in your Angular app.

Comment: I removed whole router.get("/reset-password/:id/:token") {} and it still works fine. Thank you!